# Are scattering experiments probabilistic in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, probability, time-evolution, determinism

Suppose we have a electron that will scatter into an atom. When the electron is far way of the atom long before the scattering the system is represented by the state      $\left|\psi_\text{in}\right\rangle$ . After the scattering the system will be in the state $\left|\psi_\text{out}\right\rangle$.

Is this state $\left|\psi_\text{out}\right\rangle$ obtained probabilistic from the state $\left|\psi_\text{in}\right\rangle$ or obtained deterministic from $\left|\psi_\text{in}\right\rangle$ in the sense
$$\left|\psi_\text{out}\right\rangle =U(T)\left|\psi_\text{in}\right\rangle$$

where $U(t)$ is the evolution operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pre-scattering state vector $|\psi(0)\rangle\equiv |\psi_{in}\rangle$ evolves into the post-scattering state vector $|\psi(T)\rangle \equiv |\psi_{out}\rangle$ deterministically, via the unitary propagator $U(T)$.  The outcomes of *measurements* performed on the post-scattering state, however, are non-deterministic and can only be understood probabilistically.

There are interpretations of quantum mechanics (e.g. many worlds) in which all evolution is deterministic, and the final state (which encompasses both the electron and the measurement apparatus) is entangled. However, from the perspective of a physicist standing in a laboratory wondering where the next electron will hit the detector, the measurement process is effectively non-deterministic.  The precise nature of this apparently non-deterministic evolution is the subject of the [measurement problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_problem), and remains an important open question.

Comment: suppose $|\psi(T)\rangle \equiv |\psi_{out}\rangle$ is an eingenstate of  an operator $O$, than in this case the measurement of $O$ is deterministically?

Comment: If $|\psi_{out}\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $O$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then a measurement of $O$ will return a value $\lambda$ with probability $1$.  I would hesitate to call that deterministic evolution, because then the question of whether measurements are deterministic or not depends on (1) the state of the system and (2) the quantity being measured, which sounds like a dreadful conceptual quagmire.